# C++ library for log parsing

Tags: c++, parsing, unix, logging

Is there any C++ library specifically for log parsing (helping recognize multiline events)?
Like MergeLog for Apache logs or libcurl for web parsing?

Comment: Yeah, it is called boost::regex.

Comment: Maybe Maxim's suggestion will really be enough for this case.

Boost.Xpressive looks nicer though, 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/xpressive.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you stumble upon a suitable library, my advice would be to use a standalone lexer.

- Instead of flex + bison, use [flex alone](https://github.com/westes/flex) (C/C++).
- Instead of ocamllex + ocamlyacc, use [ocamllex alone](http://plus.kaist.ac.kr/~shoh/ocaml/ocamllex-ocamlyacc/ocamllex-tutorial/sec-toy-language.html) (OCaml).
- [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) (C/C++/Objective C/D/Java/Ruby).

This way you avoid having to define a grammar (which is kind of pointless for log files anyway) and you avoid the dreaded frankenstein-regex-monster sometimes seen in dark places.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any log parsing libraries.  You could always use a general-purpose parser generator, like [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/index.html), [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), or [lex / yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/); that approach would probably be more work, but it's extremely flexible.

If a parser generator is overkill, then I'd just throw a lot of regexes at the logfiles.

Comment: Thanks Josh,
yacc/lex looks a little heavy on the programmer.

Comment: You can skip the parser part and use a standalone lexer. This is much more convenient than a bunch of unstructured regexes and way easier than a full blown parser.

Comment: @stack_zen: Spirit, ANTLR, and lex/yacc all fill the same role, more or less.  Spirit and ANTLR are more modern and probably easier to learn.  All of them can be a bit heavy, as you said, but they're powerful tools.

Comment: Spirit looks the most elegant solution for C++, syntax looks like it takes some getting used to but flexible and powerful.

I've read nice things about Antlr using other languages, but seems awkward compared to Spirit.

I'm split between Spirit and this one I've bumped into,
http://code.google.com/p/lemon-parser-generator/

LALR parser generator ... does the same job as "bison" and "yacc". 
• Different grammar syntax less prone to programming errors.
• More sophisticated, faster parsing engine thread-safe